# compare two tuple lists and then return true/false

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
lst = [('NOUN', 'chip'), ('NOUN', 'potato'), ('potato', 'chip')]

permute_lst = [('NOUN', 'chip'), ('potato', 'chip'), ('potato', 'bbq'), ('NOUN', 'potato'), ('potato', 'crisp')]
```

I want to compare these two lists of tuples in a self-defined function to return a list of Booleans. My current code:

```
def get_tf(lst):
  tf_list = []
  for lookup in permute_lst:
    if set(lst) == set(lookup):
        tf_list.append(True)
    else:
        tf_list.append(False)
  return tf_list
```

The result `tf_list=[False, False, False, False, False]`

My expected result is like:

```
tf_list = [True, True, False, True, False]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compare the two tuple lists"? Compare them based on what?

Comment: `len(get_tf(lst))` is 5 for me, can you add the sequence of commands that gets you to 15?

Comment: to check whether tuples in `lst` are in `permute_lst` or not.

Comment: Explanations are best [edit]ed into the question.

Comment: @chris I'm sorry I think I messed up the result in my jupyter notebook. the length is 5 but the result is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension that simply checks to see whether each of your `permute_list` items is in the reference list:

```
return [pair in lst for pair in permute_lst]
```

Output:

```
[True, True, False, True, False]
```